# Django Session Management in Android

Tags: android, django, cookies

I have an Android client talking to a Django backend. These are the steps I do to log in the user.

1. GET the login page.
2. Fetch the sessionid and csrftoken cookies.
3. POST back with the username, password and the sessionid and csrftoken cookies.

So far so good. I am able to login.

But when I want to GET any other page which requires the user to be logged in, I get an error.

I viewed the page in a browser, and found that it only requires the sessionid and csrftoken cookies, which I am supplying.

But I still get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:436)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:416)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:365)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:301)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
…
```

Why would authentication fail when I supply the the sessionid and the csrftoken?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you passing sessionID and csrf token

Comment: `for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
     urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
`
   }

Comment: use apache http client. Set cookie by
 BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("abc", "123"); HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore); HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

Comment: I solved it. I changed the Tastypie authentication to BasicAuthentication, and set the Basic Authentication in the HttpUrlConnection header.

Comment: @pAppaya I know your question is old, but i'm having the same issue. How did you manage to solve that? Thanks